# Covering a NO-OP Condition

Tags: java, test-coverage

I have a Java project where a coverage analysis tool is being used (SonarQube).  It rightly declared that code similar to this was a potential performance issue (`Encode.forJava` would still be called if the log level was above INFO).

```
public static String foo(String bar) {
  log.info(Encode.forJava(bar))
  ...
}
```

The fix suggested was to ensure that methods used for info logs are only called if the INFO level is actually enabled, i.e.

```
public static String foo(String bar) {
  if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
    log.info(Encode.forJava(bar))
  }
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately, this code induced Sonar to start declaring that there was only partial coverage because the condition where INFO is not enabled is not tested.  This is the root of my problem: There is deliberately no code for that condition.  I believe that Sonar would be satisfied by something like this:

```
  if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
    log.info(Encode.forJava(bar))
  } else {
    // no-op
  }
```

What are the best practices here?  Adding code to satisfy an arbitrary rule seems like the wrong way to resolve this.

Comment: Sidestepping the problem: find a logging framework which handles this for you automatically by making the parameter to your log methods a callback rather than a literal string (the callback is then invoked only if the log level is enabled).

Comment: That's not really a solution.  I could just pick a different language that allows constructs like `log.isInfoEnabled() && log.info(...)`, but that's not a solution either.  Looking for a way to write this sort of code in the existing context.

Comment: What happens if you just add a test where `isInfoEnabled` returns false?  It reads like the complaint is that you're not testing the false case, not that there isn't an explicitly-written `else` condition.

Comment: @Craig that worked, thanks.  Still don't like the idea of writing a test for code that doesn't exist but at least the code has been refactored into a place that by definition is aware of testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core issue here is that the static analysis tool doesn't know if the method `Encode.forJava(bar)` has a beneficial side effect. I.e. that if you didn't call it that something else would break.

I am not sure what capabilities Sonar has, but I would prefer to be able to declare that `Encode.forJava` is side effect free - rather than trying to Suppress the warnings when the method is invoked (or not invoked in this case).

All that said, if this is beyond the capabilities of a particular tool it may be necessary just to suppress the warnings at the call site.

Comment: This was helpful, thank you.  It provides a meaningful reason for either suppressing the warning or for creating a test case to cover the code.

Answer (score 3):

Automated checking tools have the purpose of catching errors made through thoughtlessness.  That is why they almost always have overrides to declare "Yes, I *did* think about that condition and it's deliberately absent." I'm fairly confident Sonar allows you to disable specific rules in specific places somehow, and that's what you should do.

Comment: Been at this for decades and I've never seen else //no op do anything but annoy me. (Well it also promotes awareness of coverage analysis tools. Which is probably the point.)

Comment: @candied_orange that's a big part of why I don't want to do it.  Honestly I should just suppress warnings on the original `log.info(bar)` and be done with it.

Comment: I'm aware of things like `@SuppressWarnings` (which is present on code where the consideration you mention was used), however I am loathe to suppress warnings on code that does not exist.

Comment: @Tibrogargan first see if there isn't a way to configure the tool that doesn't pollute your code base with awareness of it. [I may have found a way](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/24734/how-to-deactivate-a-rule-in-sonarqube).

Comment: @candied_orange Thanks for finding that.  Unfortunately the deployment environment has corporate managed quality rules, getting them changed is not a hill I'm about to die on.

Answer (score -1):

`isInfoEnabled()` is effectively a boolean parameter, which is usually a code smell. In this case, this code:

```java
  if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
    log.info(Encode.forJava(bar))
  }
```

is breaking the idea of [tell, don't ask](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html).

A better alternative would be to have the `log` object configured in a way that its `info` object does nothing if it's not enabled. (`isInfoEnabled()` protbably shouldn't even be a public method)

Comment: The issue is actually a performance problem because `Encode.forJava()` is called even when info logging is not enabled - which is precisely why the `log.info(Encode.forJava(...))` call is wrapped.

Comment: The usual approach for this kinda thing, if feasible, is to use a lambda which lazily produces the message, only when needed. Would that work for your case?

Comment: Yes (but).  I might be being overly sensitive about polluting the code base but I really want to avoid adding production code that is only there to satisfy a test coverage constraint.  The issue was resolved by adding an additional test case, which is still not optimal but at least test cases are literally there for tests - coverage included.

Comment: Actually, nothing I've said is really specific to testing. It's just a better design from a prod perspective, as well. E.g. it makes it impossible to forget the `isInfoEnabled()` check (which would cause you to emit an `info` msg even though it was supposed to be disabled). Have a look at [Log4j's API](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html) for reference. It offers an overload of `.info` that takes a `String` (for when the msg construction is cheaper than a lambda), *and* one that takes a `Supplier` (for when the msg is expensive).

Comment: You're focusing on the wrong element.  The issue is that the test coverage suite wants to test what happens when the condition is false, but there was no code to test until the suggested solution for the `Encode` thing was implemented.  Yes, the Supplier route could have been taken - but that would be adding insult to injury

Comment: Hey @Tibrogargan "but that would be adding insult to injury" Sorry, I don't think I follow, what's the insult, and what's the injury? As far as I see it, using a lambda both solves your testing issue (it removes the `if` statement, so there's no extra coverage needed, just assert that the `info` was called on the provided logger), while also being a more robust design for prod.

Comment: [Add insult to injury:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/add%20insult%20to%20injury) The coverage analysis suite suggested adding code that caused more coverage issues.  Having to change existing prod code again (i.e,. requiring yet more coverage tests for the new code) compounds the problem because the new prod code itself requires more tests to cover it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148986/discussion-between-alexander-and-tibrogargan).

Comment: You’d really have to explain to me where you are seeing a “code smell”.

Comment: @gnasher729 it should not be a job for the users of a logger to check its configuration and change their behaviour. It should be the loggers job to enforce its invariants that info-level messages aren’t logged when the info level is disabled.

Comment: And a code smell doesn’t mean something is necessarily bad. It just arouses suspicion and warrants further investigation. In this case, what OP did would be perfectly reasonable if there was a performance constrain that would prohibit the allocation of lambdas for each logger call.

Comment: So what you call a “code smell” is just a meta version of ops problem? “I have solution that works just fine but Alexander calls it a code smell”.

Comment: @gnasher729 hey man, I’m not sure your what your issue is, but you’re coming off real dick-ish. I like you and your answers, but chill out.